# PHP : Read Timeout error

Tags: php, apache, timeout, gateway, phpexcelreader

I am facing a read timeout problem from couple of days.

1. There is a facility to upload users in my application (Xls,xlsx are allowed extensions). This is completely admin panel.
2. I am using PHPExcel for reading the data from the sheet and inserting each row details into database on the fly.
3. Here, there is a possibility to upload large size files. Right now the file I am having is 16MB file which contains nearly 200k records.
4. I have increased below configurations through htaccess

   > php_value memory_limit 1024M
   >
   > php_value max_execution_time 259200
   >
   > php_value max_input_time 3000
   >
   > php_value post_max_size 700M
   >
   > php_value upload_max_filesize 100M

I have placed set_time_limit(0) in the specific controller also.

My problem is read timeout in production environment. It is executing for around 15 mins and returning the below error

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://example.com/upload/url

The following error was encountered:

    Read Timeout 

The system returned:

    [No Error]

A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.
```

Will Keep Alive do something here. It is set to 5 in production and Apache timeout is 300.

I have searched many of the similar errors post in this site but no luck

I am planing to set a cron job, uploading the files only from front end. Hope that will solve this but I also want to know what factor is causing this error.

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions anywhere?

Comment: No, in this functionality I am not using any sessions

Comment: This does not sound like a process that should be run from the browser. Can you not just save the uploaded file and get a cron job to process the data

Comment: Yes. I am planing the same. But this is working in our test and staging environments. Even the RAM and CPU's everything is same. But I think some config value setting is missing. I have even compared the configurations of the environments. Difference is with Keep-Alive and timeout. and few modules are missing. Just want to know what is causing this error. I am anyhow planing for a cron job.